# How to explode (or pop) array of JSON twice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to pop MongoDB documents that consist array of JSON by using `pop`, usually it works well if  MongoDB documents is only JSON, in array of JSON it produce too much column, so I can't pop to non-JSON format easily. for more detailed question I give explanation below

Here's my data

```
Id locations
1   [{'timestamp': 2018-05-28 15:00:00, 'lat': 0.0..
2   [{'timestamp': 2018-05-28 15:00:00, 'lat': 0.0..
```

What I try to pop

`df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('locations').values.tolist(), index=df.index))`

The output is

```
Id   0                              1                            ...      136
1   {'timestamp': 2018-05-28...    {'timestamp': 2018-05-28...           {'timestamp': 2018-05-28... 
2   {'timestamp': 2018-05-28...    {'timestamp': 2018-05-28...           None
```

The output that I expected is

```
Id   0                             
1   {'timestamp': 2018-05-28... 
1.  {'timestamp': 2018-05-28... 
    ...
    {'timestamp': 2018-05-28... 
2   {'timestamp': 2018-05-28...
    ...
    {'timestamp': 2018-05-28...
```

So, I can pop again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need `melt`:

```
df2 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('locations').values.tolist(), index=df.index)).melt('Id')
```

Or [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = (pd.DataFrame(df.pop('locations').values.tolist(), index=df.index)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

df2 = df.join(s.rename('new'))
```

Or numpy solution with repeat `Id` values and flatenning nested `list`s:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        "Id": np.repeat(df.Id.values, df.locations.str.len()),
        "new": list(chain.from_iterable(df.locations))})
print (df2)
   Id                                               new
0   1  {'timestamp': '2018-05-28 15:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}
1   1  {'timestamp': '2018-05-28 16:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}
2   2  {'timestamp': '2018-05-28 10:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}
3   2  {'timestamp': '2018-05-28 17:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}
4   2  {'timestamp': '2018-05-28 18:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}
```

**Setup**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2], 
                   'locations':[[{'timestamp': '2018-05-28 15:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}, {'timestamp': '2018-05-28 16:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}],
                                [{'timestamp': '2018-05-28 10:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}, {'timestamp': '2018-05-28 17:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}, {'timestamp': '2018-05-28 18:00:00', 'lat': 0.0}]]})
print (df)


   Id                                          locations
0   1  [{'timestamp': '2018-05-28 15:00:00', 'lat': 0...
1   2  [{'timestamp': '2018-05-28 10:00:00', 'lat': 0...
```

Comment: works, but not as expected, still debugging, probably mistake in my side

Comment: the first is give different output that I expected, the third `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'locations'` but the second works very well